# ajax submit always return false

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, forms

I have form for user to submit that I render as partial view in the layout page.
I'm using this script for submitting the partial view and it according to the breackpoint I have placed on it is always return false and the data does submit to the Db and the form is not clearing the data on it. I also have a small script on the submit button but the breackpoint never get there .
here are the scripts i'm using :

```
 $('#contact').submit(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: this.action,
        type: this.method,
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function (result) {
            $('#contact').html(result);
        }
    });
    return false;
});

$("#Send").bind('click', function (event) {
    $("#contact").submit();
});
```

Comment: So what is your expected behaviour? The FORM to be submitted once request is done? Or just the FORM to have all inputs resetted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're telling it to `return false`. The Ajax is run asynchronously so the code will just initiate the Ajax, and then go to the next step - return false. It doesn't have time to hit the `success` (before returning false).

Instead I would do something like this:

```
$('#contact').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault(); //prevents the submit
    $.ajax({
        url: this.action,
        type: this.method,
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        datatype : 'html',
        success: function (result) {
            $('#contact').html(result);
        }
    });
});
```

You could also choose to run the Ajax synchronously, by adding option `async: false`, but this is not recommended.

As mentioned by A. Wolff in the comments, `return false` and `e.preventDefault` essentially does the same thing.

If the Ajax is not successful though, that handler will never be triggered. Perhaps adding a handler for `error` would clarify where the error really comes from:

```
$.ajax({
    url: this.action,
    type: this.method,
    data: $(this).serialize(),
    datatype : 'html',
    success: function (result) {
       $('#contact').html(result);
    },
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
       alert("Status: " + textStatus + " Error: " + errorThrown);  
    }
});
```

Comment: `It doesn't have time to hit the success` No, it doesn't work like that. It would if the FORM was submitted but OP is using `return false;` which prevents it

Comment: @A.Wolff What I mean is the event will return false before the success will be returned. I see now that I might have been too quick though, since I'm not sure what he/she wants to happen after.

Comment: thanks, I have tried this but the data is not clearing from the page (same results) i'm tryint to load this partailview after >  return PartialView("_bla");

Comment: Ok i see what you meant but a jQuery event always returns the previous matched set of elements. Here `return false;` is a shorthand for `event.preventDefault(); event.stopPropagation();`

Comment: @Danny If you want to clear data of the FORM, then in success callback, call: `$('#contact').get(0).reset();`  EDIT: i see in your success callback you are using `$('#contact').html(result);` so i'm still not sure what is your issue. Is at least the success callback fired or not???

Comment: success: function (result) {
            $('#contact').get(0).result(); Did not clear the form.

Comment: @Danny so success callback isn't fired

Comment: @Danny see updated answer. Wolff: Thanks for the heads up on `return false` vs `e.preventDefault`. I didn't think it through properly

Comment: @A.Wolff i'm getting > undefined

Comment: @Danny What returns `undefined`? Anyway, you should provide minimalistic sample in question itself replicating your issue$

Comment: success: function (result) {
            $('#contact').get(0).result();  >>undefined

Comment: @Danny Wait this is `$('#contact').get(0).reset();` not `$('#contact').get(0).result();`...

Comment: He seems to return a partial view from the action though, so this is probably not about resetting the form but rather replacing it with the partial view. Or?

Comment: @Mackan Ok i forgive, i don't know how partial views are handled, i'm not an ASP guy ;)

Comment: $('#contact').get(0).reset(); > 
function reset() {
    [native code]
} and not clearing the form

Comment: @Mackan Yes it's the best  way I think one get to do with the other , no?

Comment: @Danny if you're returning a normal html response (partial view), then you should leave it as you had it from the beginning: `$('#contact').html(result);` :) You were not really clear about what you're returning, hence the confusion. Add `datatype : "html"` to the Ajax options also.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `preventDefault`?

```
$('#contact').submit(function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   $.ajax({
       url: this.action,
       type: this.method,
       data: $(this).serialize(),
       success: function (result) {
           $('#contact').html(result);
       }
   });
});
```

**EDIT**

You have the submit handler for the `#contact` which certainly is a form. Your success function will put the partial view returned from the controller inside the... `#contact`? Is this really what you want? If you want to replace the form with a blank one, your partial view should contain only the form fields as you are trying to post your html into the `#contact`, which is a form. Maybe you want to target some other div?

Comment: Indeed it is. It happens that I posted mine seconds before him and he certainly was typing his answer while I posted mine, so he must have missed my posting

Comment: Yes, chiapa was indeed some seconds quicker :) Afraid it was not the correct solution though

Comment: I want to target it to a diff partial view that will render in the original page. so far it look like the script is working fine.and my problem is the partial view . I will ask a new question  about it.